# How to implement early exit / return in Haskell?

Tags: java, haskell, control-structure

I am porting a Java application to Haskell. The main method of the Java application follows the pattern:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  if (args.length == 0)
  {
    System.out.println("Invalid number of arguments.");

    System.exit(1);
  }

  SomeDataType d = getData(arg[0]);
  if (!dataOk(d))
  {
    System.out.println("Could not read input data.");

    System.exit(1);
  }

  SomeDataType r = processData(d);
  if (!resultOk(r))
  {
    System.out.println("Processing failed.");

    System.exit(1);
  }

  ...
}
```

So I have different steps and after each step I can either exit with an error code, or continue to the following step.

My attempt at porting this to Haskell goes as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
         a <- getArgs
         if (null args)
           then do
                   putStrLn "Invalid number of arguments."
                   exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
           else do
                   -- The rest of the main function goes here.
```

With this solution, I will have lots of nested `if-then-else` (one for each exit point of the original Java code).

Is there a more elegant / idiomatic way of implementing this pattern in Haskell? In general, what is a Haskell idiomatic way to implement an early exit / return as used in an imperative language like Java?

Comment: Please read the example of Walking the Line from http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads page. It gives example of Monad using Maybe datatype. Once the result of any expression is Nothing, the result of all following expressions are Nothing, as good as you have exited at the failure point.

Comment: @ManojR - Maybe isn't really suitable here since you also want the reason for the failure.

Comment: The classic approach is splitting the process into a "trusting" processing function (that assumes parameters are correct) and a "paranoid" sanity check function (that only checks if parameters are correct)...

Comment: Please please please do not check for an empty list using `length`. Use `null` if you actually *need* to simply check, but prefer pattern matching, because that combines the check with giving a name to the list element(s) so you can use them.

Comment: @C. A. McCann: Thanks. I normally use `null`. `length` slipped in from the Java original and I did not care too much about it because I expect the list of arguments to be rather short. But, yes, `null` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly more sensible approach in Haskell that uses the same sort of conditional logic you tried might look like this:

```
fallOverAndDie :: String -> IO a
fallOverAndDie err = do putStrLn err
                        exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getArgs
          case a of
              [d] | dataOk d  -> doStuff $ processData d
                  | otherwise -> fallOverAndDie "Could not read input data."
              _ -> fallOverAndDie "Invalid number of arguments."


processData r 
    | not (resultOk r) = fallOverAndDie "Processing failed."
    | otherwise        = do -- and so on...
```

In this particular case, given that `exitWith` terminates the program *anyway*, we could also dispense with the nested conditionals entirely:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getArgs
          d <- case a of
                   [x] -> return x
                   _   -> fallOverAndDie "Invalid number of arguments."
          when (not $ dataOk d) $ fallOverAndDie "Could not read input data."
          let r = processData d
          when (not $ resultOk r) $ fallOverAndDie "Processing failed."
```

Using the same `fallOverAndDie` as before. This is a much more direct translation of the original Java.

In the general case, the `Monad` instance for `Either` lets you write something very similar to the latter example above in pure code. Starting from this instead:

```
fallOverAndDie :: String -> Either String a
fallOverAndDie = Left

notMain x = do a <- getArgsSomehow x
               d <- case a of
                        -- etc. etc.
```

...the rest of the code is unchanged from my second example. You can of course use something other than just `String` as well; to more faithfully recreate the `IO` version, you could use `Either (String, ExitCode)` instead.

Additionally, this use of `Either` is not limited to error handling--if you have some complicated calculation returning a `Double`, using `Either Double Double` and the same monadic style as above, you can use `Left` to bail out early with a return value, then wrap the function using something like `either id id` to collapse the two outcomes and get a single `Double`.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use the `ErrorT` monad transformer. With it, you can treat it like a regular monad, return, bind, all that good stuff, but you also get this function, `throwError`. This causes you to skip the following calculations either till you reach the end of the monadic computation, or when you call catchError. This is for error handling though, it's not meant to be for arbitrarily exiting a function in Haskell. I suggested it because it seems like that's what you're doing.

A quick example:

```
import Control.Monad.Error
import System.Environment

data IOErr = InvalidArgs String | GenErr String deriving (Show)
instance Error IOErr where
  strMsg = GenErr --Called when fail is called
  noMsg  = GenErr "Error!"
type IOThrowsError = ErrorT IOErr IO

process :: IOThrowsError [String]
process = do
  a <- liftIO getArgs
  if length a == 0
  then throwError $ InvalidArgs "Expected Arguments, received none"
  else return a

main = do 
  result <- runErrorT errableCode
  case result of
     Right a -> putStrLn $ show a
     Left  e -> putStrLn $ show e
  where errableCode = do
    a <- process
    useArgs a
```

now if process threw an error, useArgs wouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have came up with

```
data ExtendedMaybe a = Just a | GenErr String 

isWrongArgs :: [string] -> ExtendedMaybe [string]
isWrongArgs p = if (length p == 0)
then GenErr "Invalid number of arguments"
else p

getData :: ExtendedMaybe [string] -> ExtendedMaybe sometype 
getData GenErr = GenErr
getData [string] = if anything wrong return GenErr "could not read input data"

processdata :: ExtendedMaybe sometype -> ExtendedMaybe sometype
processdata GenErr = GenErr 

main = do 
    a <- getArgs
    d <- isWrongArgs a
    r <- getData d
    f <- processdata r
```

Roughly the idea is you have a datatype like Maybe a, only instead of Nothing you have GenErr String, which you define in every function which process data. If the input data type is GenErr simply return that. Otherwise check the error in the data and return GenErr with appropriate string. This may not be the perfect way, but still one way. This do not exit at the exact point of error, but guarantee that not much is happening after error occurred.

Comment: Your `ExtendedMaybe` type is basically the same as `Either String`